# Scriptural remedies for Sade-Sati ( साढ़े साती )?

Tags: astrology, shani

The [Sade-Sati: *sāḍhṛha - sātī* ( साढ़े साती )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sade_Sati)

> The *sāḍhṛha - sātī* - Sade-Sati is the 7+1⁄2 years long period of Shani. This astrological phase is much feared by those in India who believe Indian Astrology. **This is a period with many challenges, but also a time of great achievements and recognition.**

As per an astrology site, my transit chart is showing as only 20 percent goodness to me out of 100 percent for almost 5 years from 2023 i.e.almost completely bad luck and nothing favors me.

As per the astrological beliefs, therefore, It might be highly difficult time during that period.

---

**Question:**

So, I'm looking for remedies explicitly suggested by the canonical Indian Astrology texts. Which scriptures describe detailed remedies to ameliorate or mitigate the negative effects of Sade-Sati?

***What are some remedies, explicitly prescribed by the canonical Astrology scriptures, to help through the difficult period of Sade-Sati?***

Comment: Basically you have to perform remedies to pacify Shani. Shade Shati doesn't always give bad results. It depends on whether Shani is malefic or afflicted in the particular chart.@user2225190

Comment: @Rickross, could you suggest how do I know that, I completed one sade-sati in my childhood, so concerned again now :)

Comment: An astrologer can tell you that by inspecting your birth chart (horoscope). Regarding remedies of Shani you can get a lot from the web. For example see this (https://parenting.firstcry.com/articles/magazine-remedies-to-reduce-the-effect-of-shani-sade-sati/) and this (https://www.astrologerankitsharma.com/shani-dosha-cause-effects-remedies.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the extant jyotish (Astrology) scriptures discuss *sade-sati* or not. However, we do have remedies in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa.

This follows from the famous encounter of Pippalāda Muni and the Lord of the planet Saturn - Sanaiścara (Shani).

Pippalāda got the following remedies as a boon from Shani.

> #### [Chapter 174](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502153.html), Tīrtha-māhātmya,
>
> Nāgara-khaṇḍa Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa
>
> अध्यर्द्धाष्टमिकायोगे तावके संस्थिते नरः । तववारे तु संप्राप्ते
> यस्तिलाँल्लोहसंयुतान् ॥ ८७ ॥
>  स्वशक्त्या राति नो तस्य पीडा कार्या
> त्वया विभो । कृष्णां गां यस्तु विप्राय तवोद्देशेन यच्छति ॥ ८८ ॥
> अध्यर्द्धाष्टमजा पीडा नाऽस्य कार्या त्वया विभो । शमी समिद्भिर्यो होमं
> तवोद्देशेन यच्छति ॥ ८९ ॥
>  तथा कृष्णतिलैश्चैव कृष्णपुष्पानुलेपनैः ।
> पूजां करोति यस्तुभ्यं धूपं वै गुग्गुलं दहेत् ।
>  कृष्णवस्त्रेण
> संवेष्ट्य त्याज्या तस्य व्यथा त्वया ॥ ९० ॥
>
> > Pippalāda said -
>
> > - 87-90. **During the seven and a half years of your malefic period, if someone tries to consume gingelly seeds with some metal on Saturdays,
> >   he should not be troubled by you**, O Lord.
>
> > - **If anyone gives a black cow to a Brāhmiṇa with you in view, O Lord, you must desist from afflicting him during those seven and a half
> >   years**.
>
> > - If anyone performs Homa unto you with Śamī twigs, covers your image with black cloth, worships you with black gingelly seeds, black
> >   flowers and unguents and offers incense burning Guggulu, you must
> >   avoid harassing him.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare.

---

Therefore, to conclude

### Remedies for the *Sade-sati* are -

<sup>*(as per the Skanda & Shiva Purāṇa)*</sup>

- Consuming gingelly seeds (til) from a metal utensil on a Saturday during the period of the *Sade-sati*.
- Donation of a Black Cow to a Brāhmiṇa, with Shani as the presiding deity.
- Performing (with devotion) the Śāntika (pacificatory) rites and Homa with gingelly seeds along with sacrificial twigs (of Śamī tree) and raw rice grains on Saturday, as asked as a boon by King Daśaratha in Skandapurāṇa Verse [6.1.96.35-39](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493460.html).
- Hearing or reading the story of Pippalāda Muni as found in the [Shiva Purāṇa 7.24-25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226420.html), (vide. cf. infra Shiva Purāṇa Verse [7.25.19-20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226421.html))

Comment: If I recall correctly , there was one more incident...Umm..Something b/w Lord Hanuman and Lord Shani. Can you throw some light on this?

Comment: But I don't know if the text describes Hanumāna as a remedy for Shani though @LSSJBROLY